# Ruby on Rails IBAN validation in model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, iban

I'm trying to do iban validation as any country iban code. I got some of help from stackoverflow for build that code but still I have some problem and I don't know where is it.

Always I get 'That is not a valid IBAN' error message. But sometimes I tried correct iban code as defined countries.

Is there anybody help me in that code for doing this validation, please?

The code is here:

```
  class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :bank_name, presence: true
  validate :iban, :valid_iban?, presence: true

  private

    def valid_iban?
            ibans = iban.upcase.scan(/\w/).join

            ibans = ibans.gsub(/_/, '')

            iban_length = ibans.length

            country = ibans.scan(/\A../).join

            length_correct_for_country = true

            case country
                when "IE"
                    if iban_length == 22
                        length_correct_for_country = true
                    else
                        length_correct_for_country = false      
                    end
                when "AL"
                    if iban_length == 28
                        length_correct_for_country = true
                    else
                        length_correct_for_country = false      
                    end
                when "TR"
                    if iban_length == 26
                        length_correct_for_country = true
                    else
                        length_correct_for_country = false      
                    end
                when "GB"
                    if iban_length == 22
                        length_correct_for_country = true
                    else
                        length_correct_for_country = false      
                    end
                when "VG"
                    if iban_length == 24
                        length_correct_for_country = true
                    else
                        length_correct_for_country = false      
                    end
            end

            first_four_characters = ibans.slice!(0..3)

            reordered_number = ibans + first_four_characters

            letters_removed = []
            reordered_number.scan(/./) do |character|
                case character
                when "A"
                    letters_removed << 10
                when "9"
                    letters_removed <<9
                end
            end

            letters_removed = letters_removed.join.to_i

            remainder = letters_removed % 97

            if remainder == 1 && length_correct_for_country

            else
                remainder = remainder.to_s
                errors.add(:iban, " That is not a valid IBAN. The IBAN that is being supplied")
            end

    end

end
```

Comment: It should be `validate :valid_iban?` and `validates :iban, presence: true` two separate validations, you should pass a method to `validate`.

Comment: I did it just now. But the problem is same. I think it is in the validation code

Comment: So your condition: `remainder == 1 && length_correct_for_country` is always being evaluated to false, check if your logic is correct then.

Comment: I just read this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number There are multiple problems in your code. For example: You do not check the length for all possible country codes or your code to generate the checksum does not handle all possible character replacements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [iban-tools](https://github.com/alphasights/iban-tools) gem is available for this purpose and it works very well.

To use the gem in Rails I recommend to write a validator class.

First put this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'iban-tools'
```

and run `bundle`.

Then create a new directory `app/validators` and inside that a file called `iban_validator.rb` with these contents:

```
require 'iban-tools'

class IbanValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless IBANTools::IBAN.valid?(record.iban)
      record.errors.add :iban, record.errors.generate_message(:iban, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

In your model class put this:

```
validates_with IbanValidator
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension to the solution of @Joost Baaij.

To use it like any other Rails validator you can use the ActiveModel::EachValidator:

```rb
require 'iban-tools'

class IbanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if IBANTools::IBAN.valid?(value)

    record.errors.add attribute, record.errors.generate_message(:attributes, :invalid)
  end
end
```

Then you can use this in your model:

```rb
validates bank_number, iban: true
```

Answer (score 0):

you need probably something like:

```
validate :valid_iban?

def valid_iban?

end
```

Comment: my current code like that:
validate :valid_iban?
  validates :iban, presence: true
but the problem is same

Comment: maybe problem is here: `letters_removed <<9` it should be `letters_removed << 9`

Comment: maybe you should thing to change the code of validation. there is one gem which does iban checking: [link](https://rubygems.org/gems/iban-check)